# TMOUT within script file misbehaves for the select command. How to fix it?

Tags: bash, timeout, select

**UPDATE** - looks like this is something peculiar with bash 4.3.42 as it works fine with 4.3.46. Leaving this post for those who run into the same issue in future.

When I run this command in bash command line it works properly:

```
% (TMOUT=3; s="no selection"; select s in a b c ; do break ; done; echo $s)
1) a
2) b
3) c
#?
no selection
% _
```

Result: displays *no selection* and comes back to command line.

When, however, I place it a script, and execute it, it repetitively requests selection.

```
% cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash
(TMOUT=3; s="no selection"; select s in a b c ; do break ; done; echo $s)

% ./a.sh
```

Result:

```
1) a
2) b
3) c
#? 1) a
2) b
3) c
#? 1) a
2) b
3) c
#? ^C
% _
```

Why it so? My main question is - **how to make it work in a script?!**

**UPDATED**

```
% bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

% uname
Linux lx1 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 24 10:22:33 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me using a BASH script on a BASH shell (i.e. timeout after 3 seconds). I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. There must be something odd about your setup. What operating system are you using? What version of bash (`bash --version`)?

Comment: Must be something peculiar with 4.3.42 as 4.3.46 works fine for me, too.

Comment: There was a bugfix in release 4.2 regarding `select` not terminating properly when `TMOUT` was set, but that's _older_ than the `bash` you're using.

Comment: @Kusalananda - That is interesting there *was* a bug like that. Maybe they re-introduced it in me version... Good to know I am not insane :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ultimately I have written my own selection that can be used in a script.

```
# $1 timeout
# rest - selection
function select_ {
  t=$1
  shift
  arr=($*)
  i=1
  for a in $*; do
    echo "$i) $a" >$(tty)
    ((i++))
  done
  echo "TIMEOUT: In ${t} seconds ${arr[0]} will be automatically selected." >$(tty)
  printf "#? " >$(tty)
  read -t $t x
  [ "$x" == "" ] && {
     x=1
     echo "$x" >$(tty)
  }
  ((x=x+0))
  [ "$x" -ge 1 -a "$x" -le ${#arr[@]} ] && {
    ((x--))
    echo ${arr[$x]}
  }
}
```

How to use it:

```
select_ 10 a b c
```

Example:

```
$ ./x.sh
1) a
2) b
3) c
TIMEOUT: In 10 seconds a will be automatically selected.
#? 2
b

$ ./x.sh
1) a
2) b
3) c
TIMEOUT: In 10 seconds a will be automatically selected.
#? 1
a
```

Answer (score 1):

From manual:

> TMOUT  If set to a value greater than zero, TMOUT is treated as the
>   default timeout for the read builtin.  The select command terminates
>   if input does not arrive after  TMOUT  seconds  when  input  is coming
>   from a terminal.  In an interactive shell, the value is interpreted as
>   the number of seconds to wait for input after issuing the primary
>   prompt. Bash terminates after waiting for that number of seconds if
>   input does not arrive.

So first case is due to interactive shell.

```
$ ps -aef|grep bash; echo "before"; (TMOUT=3; s="no selection"; ps -aef|grep bash; select s in a b c ; do break ; done; echo $s;ps -aef|grep bash);echo "after";ps -aef|grep bash
asktyagi    4926 23767  0 09:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto bash
asktyagi   23767 23741  0 09:03 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
**before**
asktyagi    4927 23767  0 09:40 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
asktyagi    4929  4927  0 09:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto bash
asktyagi   23767 23741  0 09:03 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
1) a
2) b
3) c
#?
no selection
asktyagi    4927 23767  0 09:40 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
asktyagi    4931  4927  0 09:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto bash
asktyagi   23767 23741  0 09:03 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
**after**
asktyagi    4933 23767  0 09:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto bash
asktyagi   23767 23741  0 09:03 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
```

Now with script

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash
(TMOUT=3; s="no selection"; select s in a b c ; do break ; done; echo $s)
ps -aef|grep bash

$ sh a.sh
1) a
2) b
3) c
#?
no selection
asktyagi    5201  5188  0 09:41 pts/0    00:00:00 grep bash
asktyagi   23767 23741  0 09:03 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
```

Comment: The primary prompt is not issued while running a script. In other words, the shell running a script is not an "interactive shell".

Comment: Edited my answer with more explanation, thanks.

Comment: @asktyagi Thank you for the detailed response. It still does not answer how to fix the issue, and it looks like there is no solution for that because, as I have updated my question, there seems to be a bug in bash.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `timeout` command.  This example could be improved but it makes the point.  First use the bash-builtin `trap` command to run something on exit, then run your loop. It runs as follows:

```
#] timeout 3s sh -c 'trap "echo no selection" EXIT; select s in a b c ; do break ; done; '
1) a
2) b
3) c
#? <waits 3 seconds>no selection
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! I have written my own select but out of curiosity I checked your solution. If you run this in the command line and do selection you will end up 'no selection' printed out anyway. If you run it in a script and do selection, not only you will get 'no selection' printed out but also your selection (let's say 1) will be executed as a command.

Comment: I have posted my solution I have ultimately wrote. Thanks for your interest and time!

Comment: I suppose you could clear the trap on successful exit: `trap - EXIT`. Thanks for posting your solution!